# Select row in Listview selects the last row in the list view rather that the row I select

Tags: c#, asp.net

In an aspx page I have a Listview with a select button on each row. When the select button is clicked it selects that row, but it always gets the data from the last row in the listview, rather than the one Im selecting.

The controlid is a parameter for the GetDeadline method which calls a stored procedure to select the row where the controlid column equals the controlid parameter.

```
    protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
            {
                Label mylabel = (Label)item.FindControl("ControlIDLabel");
                Session["controlid"] = mylabel.Text;
            }

            controlid = Session["controlid"].ToString();

            Deadline newdeadline = Deadline.GetDeadline(controlid);

            Bind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

And a further example of what I mean:

```
ControlID | Name      | 
---------------------------------
1           Row One     Select
2           Row Two     Select
3           Row Three   Select
4           Row Four    Select
```

No matter which row I select, mylabel.Text = "4".

How can I get that to get the data from  the correct row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get selected item and in this item find your label. If you search label in loop foreach it always set to `Session["controlid"]` last label text as value. Try use this code.

Here you can find more about [ListView.SelectedIndexChanging Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindexchanging(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)ProductsListView.Items[e.NewSelectedIndex];
               Label mylabel = (Label)item.FindControl("ControlIDLabel");
               Session["controlid"] = mylabel.Text;


                controlid = Session["controlid"].ToString();

                Deadline newdeadline = Deadline.GetDeadline(controlid);

                Bind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.